# React TypeScript error for size attribute of html input element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using create-react-app with the TypeScript template. When I write the following JSX/TSX code snippet

```
function MyInputFieldComponent() {
    return (
        <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Full Name"/>
    );
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> (JSX attribute) React.InputHTMLAttributes.size?:
>   number | undefined
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number |
>   undefined'.ts(2322)
>
> index.d.ts(2094, 9): The expected type comes from
>   property 'size' which is declared here on type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLInputElement>'

What is wrong here? Shouldn't I be able to set the html attribute "size" like any other attribute?

Comment: size is a `number,` not a `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function MyInputFieldComponent() {
    return (
        <input type="text" size={100} placeholder="Full Name"/>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did try `<input type="text" size=100 placeholder="Full Name"/>` at first, but obviously forgot about the curly braces. Thanks for pointing that out.